# How can I return only numbers and white space in Regular Expression?

Tags: regex

I would like to have a regular expression which returns only the numbers and the white space which I've inserted. i.e.

```
012 345 678
```

or

```
012 345 678 910.
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: What's the difference with [ *how can I check the input is only number and white space in regular expression?* ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656869/how-can-i-check-the-input-is-only-number-and-white-space-in-regular-expression)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove any other character except digits and white space. Here’s an example in PHP:

```
$output = preg_replace('/[^\d\s]/', '', $str);
```

Then the remaining string does only consist of digits and white space characters.

Answer (score 1):

A Java example which uses the regular expression `(\d+(\s\d)?)*`:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(\\s\\d)?)*", Pattern.CANON_EQ);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher("i.e 012 345 678 or 012 345 678 910.");
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    resultString = regexMatcher.group();
}
```