# how can I check the input is only number and white space in regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers

I have "222 22 222", "333 33 33 333", "1234/34", and "ab345 543" and I want to check whether these inputs are numeric and white space. I.E this case, the first and the second inputs should return True by using method Test of Regular Expression, or return its own value by using Exec method. The third and the fourth should return false. How could I do so in Regular Expression? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What language or tool are you using? Regular expressions have slightly different syntax in different languages.

Comment: sorry. I used Javascript

Comment: What results would you expect for `"    "` and `"1234"`. ie All whitespaces and all numerics ?

Comment: i would expect it to return 222 22 222, 333 33 33 333 the same as I have input. But the third and the fourth won't return anything or return false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can test with this regular expression:

```
/^[\d\s]+$/
```

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/QNparedNKg)

---

If you want to also check that there is at least one digit in the string:

```
/^\s*\d[\d\s]*$/
```

Comment: ^[\d\s]+$ (since i think he does not want to match empty string)

Comment: Does the OP also want to ensure there are some numerics or are they happy to match an entirely whitespace string? They aren't clear.

Comment: I added an alternative answer that ensures at least one digit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this regex: ^(?:[0-9]|\s)*$

Here's a test case in python:

```
test=["222 22 222", "333 33 33 333", "1234/34","ab345 543"]
for i in test:
    m = re.match("^(?:[0-9]|\s)*$", i)
    if (m == None): print("False")
    else: print("True: %s" % m.group())
```

The resut is:

```
True: 222 22 222
True: 333 33 33 333
False
False
```

Cheers Andrea

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be something like [\d\s{0,1}]

Comment: This will not match repeated characters