# Check validity with RegEx for explicit pattern in string - 7 digits seperated by whitespace only

Tags: regex, vba

I am trying to find a solution for a specific way to check whether a string matches the correct criteria. The string being analyzed can consist of multiple values.

Rules for the whole string:

1. value should have 7 digits only, not more not less.
2. if more than one value is available then the values should only be seperated by a whitespace

Example of correct cells:

[image]

fwiw: I am coding in VBA.

I found this useful post from user @nivox and tweaked it a little (added the rule of having 7 digits), but I have difficulties with values not being seperated at all.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3656917/9121235

My tweaked solution:
https://regex101.com/r/LGOOQW/1/

As you can see it still matches values not being seperated by a whitespace:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use `^[0-9]{7}(?:\s[0-9]{7})*$` / `^\d{7}(?:\s\d{7})*$`

Comment: you helped me again Wiktor! thanks so much, it is working flawlessly.

Comment: new line chars will still be accepted, but only a whitespace (space) is allowed. if I replace \s with " " it is still matching patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If only space from all whitespace characters is allowed:

```js
^[0-9]{7}(?: [0-9]{7})*$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/THW2Hf/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{7}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (7 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{7}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (7 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: It's returning TRUE if i have a value like 7777777 linebreak 7777777, but it should be FALSE, because linebreak is not a space char.

Comment: @smartini No idea, it **IS** [false](https://regex101.com/r/THW2Hf/2).